# T-SQL Select on exact matches on mapping columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

**TABLE A**:

```
Id      Feature 
-----------------
1             a          
2             b
3             c
4             d
```

**TABLE B**:

```
Id          AId
-----------------
1             1
1             3
2             1
3             1
3             3
3             4
4             1
4             3
```

So you could read TABLE B as

- Id 1 has the following features - a,c
- Id 2 has the following features - a
- Id 3 has the following features - a,c,d
- Id 4 has the following features - a,c

I'd like to get all IDs in Table B that has a specific feature

So for for [a,c] I want back [1,4]

The only way i can think of doing it correctly is to get csv lists for each id in TABLE B and find the ones matching my query exactly.

Does anyone have a better way? My way doesn't take advantage of the index on the table and I'd imagine would be prohibitively slower as the table gets bigger.

Comment: Which is the stamens that you have tried? Try it first then people will be willing to help

Comment: Where's your query????????

Comment: Sorry i did actaully try add the query the first time. Kept on getting errors when trying to post that i had badly formatted code.

Comment: >     SELECT Id FROM B
>     WHERE STUFF(SELECT ',' + AId from B order by Aid FOR XML PATH(''),1,1,'') >     '1,2,3'

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to concatenate the values together.  `group by` and `having` are sufficient:

```
select b.id
from b join
     a
     on b.aid = a.id
group by b.id
having sum(case when a.feature = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has "a"
       sum(case when a.feature = 'c' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has "c"
       sum(case when a.feature not in ('a', 'c') then 1 else 0 end) = 0  -- has nothing else
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I've settled on for now. Its used in a sp and it have a function that converts a csv line to a table CSVToTable.

```
declare @features nvarchar(max), @fcount int;

--using a csv list of features as input to the query
set @features = 'a,b';

--just to row count of the features
set @fcount = (select count(*) from [CSVToTable](@features))

SELECT mat.Id from 

(
    SELECT Id from B b1
    JOIN A a1 on b1.AId = a1.Id
    JOIN [CSVToTable](@features) f on f.Id = a1.Feature
    GROUP BY count(b1.Id)
    HAVING COUNT(b1.Id) = @fcount) mat
JOIN (
    SELECT Id from B b2
    GROUP BY count(b1.Id)
    HAVING COUNT(b1.Id) = @fcount) mat
) all1 on all1.Id = mat.Id
```

So its not that easy to read but I group by the first table AND INNER JOIN my created feature table with a having clause that it has exactly the same amount of features. The issue for this is that it doesn't exclude ids that have extra features eg: i want a,b but I also get ids that have a,b,c. So to fix this I inner join with all records in table B that have the same number of features.